# .NET/C# check if SQL query modifies database and if not execute

Tags: c#, .net, sql, code-injection

I know how to execute queries from C# but I want to provide a dropdown list in which people can write a query and it will execute and populate the list.

A problem is that I want to forbid all queries that modify the database in any way. I have not managed to find a way to do this and I did my best with google.

The solution I can think of is that I will scan the query for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE and only allow SELECT statements. However, I want to be able to allow users to call stored procedures as well. This means I need to get the body of the stored procedure and scan it before I execute it. How do I download a stored procedure then?

If anyone knows a way to only execute read only queries do share please! I have the feeling scanning the text for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE doesn't prevent SQL injections.

Comment: This is a SQL Injection attack waiting to happen. Your best/only secure option is to do as @dlev suggests and restrict this by permission. This might be in addition to scanning for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE but that test is not reliable enough. Only permissions can stop a user executing a bad query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do this might be to offload this job to the database. Just make sure that the database user that will be running the queries has read-access *only*. Then, any queries that do anything other than `SELECT` will fail, and you can report that failure back to the users.

If you don't go this route, the complexity becomes quite enormous, since you basically have to be prepared to parse an arbitrary SQL statement, not to mention arbitrary *sequences* of SQL statements if you allow stored procs to be run.

Even then, take care to ensure that you aren't leaking sensitive data through your queries. Directly input queries from site users can be dangerous if you're not careful. Even if you are, allowing these queries on anything but a specifically constructed sandbox database is a "whoops, I accidentally changed the user's permissions" away from becoming a security nightmare.

Another option is to write a "query creator" page, where users can pick the table and columns they'd like to see. You can then a) only show tables and columns that are appropriate for a given user (possibly based on user roles etc.) and b) generate the SQL yourself, preferably using a parameterized query.

**Update**: As Yahia points out, if the user has execute privilege (so that they can execute stored procs,) then the permissions of the procedure itself are honoured. Given that, it might be better to *not* allow arbitrary stored proc execution, but rather offer the users a list of procedures that are known to be safe. That will probably be difficult to maintain and error-prone, though, so disallowing stored procs altogether might be best.

Comment: +1 - DB permissions are the way to go.  Keyword searches will fail, since he would still allow a `SELECT INTO`, or stored procedure calls that may have damaging code inside them.

Comment: Yes, exactly my thoughts. I didn't want to be writing a whole parser for SQL. I have to check whether the users using it will have read only permission which I was assuming they will.

I want to restrict the query to a particular schema so that they can't touch the data-sensitive parts of the DB.

Comment: @user You can use per-table permissions if need be. Still, the best option might be to offer a "query creator", so you have complete control over what queries can be run and executed. This is just dangerous stuff.

Comment: executing stored procedure needs execute privilege... if the procedure itself modifies something won't be checked against the executing user's permissions but against the procedures permission - at least in Oracle you grant the procedure the needed permissions...

Answer (score 4):

How about creating a user account on the database server which only has select (read-only) rights?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could set up a SQL user with read-only access to the database and issue the command using that user?  Then you can catch the errors when/if they happen.

It seems to me that it's going to be very difficult and error-prone to try to parse the query to figure out if it modifies the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse SQL like that reliably.

Use permissions to

1. Allow only SELECT on tables and views
2. No permissions on stored procedures that change data (An end user by default won't be able to see stored procedure definition)

Answer (score 1):

Best is to not allow users to enter SQL and use only prepared/parameterized queries...

The next best way to prevent that is to use a restricted user with pure read access
The above two can be combined...

**BEWARE**
To execute a Stored Procedure the user must have execute privilege... IF the Stored Procedure modifies data then this would happen without an error messages even with a restricted user since the permission to modify is granted to the Stored Procedure!

IF you absolutely must allow users to enter SQL and can't restrict the login then you would need to use a SQL parser - for example [this](http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-dotnet.php)...

As to how to download the body of a Stored Procedure - this is dependent on the DB you use (SQL Server, Oracle etc.).

**EDIT:**

Another option are so-called "Database Firewall" - you connect instead of directly to the DB to the Firewall... in the Firewall you configure several things like time-based restrictions (when specific users/statement are/art not allowed), SQL-based statement (which are allowed...), quantity-based restrictions (like you can get 100 records, but are not able to download the whole table/DB...) etc.
There are commercial and opensource DB Firewalls out there - though these are by nature very dependent on the DB you use etc.

Examples:

- [Oracle Firewall](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-firewall/overview/index.html) - works with Oracle / SQL Server / DB2 etc.
- [SecureSphere](http://www.imperva.com/products/dsc_database-firewall.html) - several including Oracle / SQL Server / DB2 etc.
- [GreenSQL](http://www.greensql.net/) - opensource version support Postgres + MySQL, commercial MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about things that are even worse than INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE.  Like TRUNCATE...that's some bad stuff.

Answer (score 0):

i think `SQL Trigger` is the best way what you want to do.

Comment: Hello Shree and welcome to stack overflow.
In the future, when answering questions, please try to be thorough with your answer. What is SQL Trigger? What is it used for? How can it be used here? What about code examples?
It is better to be the last to answer with a great answer than be the first and be disregarded for low quality.
I suggest you edit the answer to comply with the tips above (taken from the [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) section of the stack overflow FAQ.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your first move should be to create a DB user for this specific task with only the needed permissions (basically SELECT only), and with the rights to see only the tables you need them to see (so they cannot SELECT sys tables or your users table).

More generally, it seems like a bad idea to let users execute code directly on your database. Even if you protect it against data modification, they will still be able to make ugly-looking joins to make your db run slow, for instance.

Maybe whichever language your programming the UI with, you could try to look online for a custom control that allows filtering on a database. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=filter%20control#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=C#%20filter%20control&pbx=1&oq=C#%20filter%20control&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2743l3255l0l3491l3l3l0l0l0l0l234l561l0.2.1l3l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=165bfefa6b75e1a2&biw=1280&bih=920) it...

Answer (score 0):

this is not perfect but might be what you want, this allows the keyword to appear if its a part of a bigger alphanumeric string:

```
public static bool ValidateQuery(string query)
{
    return !ValidateRegex("delete", query) && !ValidateRegex("exec", query) && !ValidateRegex("insert", query) && !ValidateRegex("alter", query) &&
           !ValidateRegex("create", query) && !ValidateRegex("drop", query) && !ValidateRegex("truncate", query);
}
public static bool ValidateRegex(string term, string query)
{
    // this regex finds all keywords {0} that are not leading or trailing by alphanumeric 
    return new Regex(string.Format("([^0-9a-z]{0}[^0-9a-z])|(^{0}[^0-9a-z])", term), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(query);
}
```

you can see how it works here: [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B%5E0-9a-z%5Ddelete%5B%5E0-9a-z%5D%29%7C%28%5Edelete%5B%5E0-9a-z%5D%29&i=11%20delete%20drop%0D%0Adelete%20*%20from%20%0D%0A%3Bdelete%20*%20from%0D%0Aselect%20*%20from%20table%3Bdelete%20*%0D%0A11delete%20%0D%0A%20deletedrop%0D%0A%27deletedrop%0D%0A11deletedrop%0D%0A)
see regex cheat sheet: [cheatsheet1](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/regex-cheatsheet-100421095826-phpapp01/95/regex-cheatsheet-1-728.jpg?cb=1271843931), [cheatsheet2](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/regular_expressions_cheat_sheet.png)

notice this is not perfect since it might block a query with one of the keywords as a quote, but if you write the queries and its just a precaution then this might do the trick.

you can also take a different approach, try the query, and if it affects the database do a rollback:

```
public static bool IsDbAffected(string query, string conn, List<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
{
    var response = false;
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        using (var transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("Test Transaction"))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection, transaction))
        {
            command.Connection = sqlConnection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = query;
            if (parameters != null)
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
            // ExecuteNonQuery() does not return data at all: only the number of rows affected by an insert, update, or delete.
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                transaction.Rollback("Test Transaction");
                response = true;
            }
            transaction.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

you can also combine the two.